# aws lambda bundling - for debian based docker image cant run apt-get command

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I am using container images for bundling and deployment of my aws lamda using cdk. Below is my sample code snippet. The issue i am facing here is not able to run any `apt` commands part of my command list. `pip` commands are working fine. Basically i am getting below error `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)` . When I googled , found I need to run the commands as `root` , but in container by default its root.

```
code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
                "./cdk_lambda_infra",
                exclude=["*.pyc"],
                bundling={
                    "image": core.DockerImage.from_registry(
                        "docker.io/library/python:3.8"
                    ),
                    "command": [
                        "bash",
                        "-c",
                        "apt-get update && pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output",
                    ],
                },
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

So Lambda does not allow to modify any files outside `/tmp`. If you need to write anything within Lambda, you need to create some files inside `/tmp` path. This is called ephemeral storage. By default, it's max size is 512 MB but it can be easily increased. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

You can also mount EFS volume to your Lambda - this way you'll be able to write into the EFS in any path you mount the volume.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/